# Using ".Any()" in lambda query throws error in .net core EF project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this below query in which throws the error below mentioned,It used to work in the other project but no able to run in the .net core project.

```
var lstAppForm = await _appDBContext.ApplicationForms.Where(qr => appFormViewModel.Any(any => any.kycId == qr.id )).ToListAsync();
```

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet
>       .Where(a => __appFormViewModel_0
>           .Any(any => any.kycId == a.id))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the expression is not translatable to sql because the `appFormViewModel` is not an entity in your database. it is your view model for UI which has nothing to do directly in the database so it shouldn't be part of your EF query any way.

What we can do is project the needed data outside the EF query using `Select` and then use it in the Linq query for EF:

```
var ids = appFormViewModel.Select(x => x.kycId).ToList();

var lstAppForm = await _appDBContext.ApplicationForms
                      .Where(qr => ids.Contains(qr.id))
                      .ToListAsync();
```

or:

```
var ids = appFormViewModel.Select(x => x.kycId).ToList();

var lstAppForm = await _appDBContext.ApplicationForms
                      .Where(qr => ids.Any(a => a == qr.id))
                      .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, but my `.Any` collection is a an entity in the `dbContext`. If needed I can provide some code.

Comment: @Julian please ask a new question with minimum code to reproduce the problem

Comment: I already did it in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64045636/entity-framework-core-postgresql-array-type-mapping-not-working
Thanks for the comment!