# Entity Framework Core postgresql Array Type Mapping not working

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have a strange problem, maybe it is something that I'm missing out, but I have the following LINQ Lambda query:

```cs
var ss = ctx.ShipZones.SelectMany(
                z => ctx.ShipDecks,
                (z, d) =>
                    new
                    {
                        Zone = z.ZIndex,
                        Deck = d.DIndex,
                        Value = ctx.Tags
                            .AsExpandable()
                            .Include(s => s.TagSettings.Device.System)
                            .Where(s =>
                                 s.TagSettings.TagTypeId == 171
                                 && s.TagSettings.Device.System.Id == z.Id
                                 && s.TagSettings.Device.ControlArea.Contains(d.Id)

                                    )
                            .Average(s => s.Value)

                    }
                ).ToList();
```

According to [this](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/array.html) article, this should be translated to this:

```sql
SELECT z.z_index AS "Zone", d.d_index AS "Deck", (
  SELECT AVG(t.value)
  FROM tags_current_data AS t
  INNER JOIN tags_settings AS t0 ON t.tag_id = t0.id
  INNER JOIN systems_devices AS s ON t0.device_id = s.id
  INNER JOIN systems AS s0 ON s.system_id = s0.id
  WHERE ((t0.tag_type_id = 171) AND (s0.id = z.id)) AND (d.id = ANY(s.control_area))) AS "Value"
FROM zones AS z
CROSS JOIN decks AS d
```

But somehow, the translated query is like this:

```sql
SELECT z.z_index AS "Zone", d.d_index AS "Deck", (
  SELECT AVG(t.value)
  FROM tags_current_data AS t
  INNER JOIN tags_settings AS t0 ON t.tag_id = t0.id
  INNER JOIN systems_devices AS s ON t0.device_id = s.id
  INNER JOIN systems AS s0 ON s.system_id = s0.id
  WHERE ((t0.tag_type_id = 171) AND (s0.id = z.id)) AND (TRUE = FALSE)) AS "Value"
FROM zones AS z
CROSS JOIN decks AS d
```

The difference is where it should be `d.id = ANY(s.control_area)` it is `TRUE = FALSE`

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Julian Dimitrov

Comment: To generate SQL like that seems to be a problem inside the library, I would be tempted to open an issue on the [Github repo](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg).

Comment: Hi David,
I've already created an issue there :) Thanks for the advice

Comment: In that case you get a thumbs-up reaction for your issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem. It is in [this](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1510) issue.

Basically:

> It was in the entities configuration. The `ControlArea` property in the `Device` entity was of type `List<long>`. When I changed it to `long[]` (long array) it worked!

Comment: Note that version 5.0 of the provider (already in rc1) has much better support for List<T>, so it shouldn't matter much anymore.